# How to rename file with the proper extension when not knowing what they are?

Tags: linux, files

I have about 100000 files in a directory without extension, i don't know what they are some seems to be pdf, jpg, png , xls etc ...

Is there a simple way to add the extension for each file ?

My current idea is to make a script that for each file will make a `file` command  on it, get the result with a grep (like grep png) with a if and add png if it's true.

If anyone have a better method.

Regards

Comment: You're looking for the `file` command, and probably a `case ... esac` construct to switch based on its output for each file

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1347359/how-can-i-get-the-extensions-of-a-file-based-on-its-content

Comment: Yes and for a bit more Documentation stuff here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-file-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you have a relatively clean list of filenames, all in one directory, and that the filenames are free of spaces, tabs, newlines, and other ill-behaved characters.  The code snippets here are intended for the `bash` shell.

## First, make a backup

Whenever you're doing an automated rename of thousands of files, there's always a chance there will be a problem.  One problem times a hundred thousand files equals a hundred thousand problems to fix before you can try again.

Start by making a backup:

```
$ mkdir ~/my-backup
$ rsync -av ./ ~/my-backup/
```

Now, if you ever flub something, you can restore from your backup:

```
$ rsync -av --delete ~/my-backup/ ./
```

## `file` varies a lot

The implementation quality of the `file` command
varies across distros.  It would seem to be a safe bet that the newer the release, the better, since the `magic` file that `file` uses will presumably be more up to date.  If you can, you may get more complete results (i.e., less hand-fiddling) by copying/`rsync`-ing the files to a machine running an OS with a better version of `file`.

## So how good is my system's `file` implementation?

Let's define a function `fext` that will run `file -b --extension` on whatever
wildcard glob we give it.  Further, we'll run the output of `file` through some simple `sed` transformations to standardize the `file` output to our liking:

```
fext () {
  file -b --extension "$@" |
  sed -e 's-^jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif$-jpg-' |
  sed -e 's-^pdf$-PDF-' |
  cat
}
```

Please pardon the useless `cat`.  It is included for modularity, so that if
you have file types that return multiple extension strings, you can copy, paste
and edit the `sed` line to translate those multiples to the single extension
you prefer, or to arbitrarily capitalize if you wish, etc.  In this example,
files that are identifed by `file` as `jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif` will be given
the extension `jpg`, while files identified as `pdf` will be given the
extension `PDF`.  The `cat` is just a no-op place-holder at the end of the
transformation list.

## What about other filetypes that have multiple extensions?

It's important to ensure that you have enumerated all possible file types in
your collection for which `file` returns multiple extensions.  This is simple
to test:

```
$ fext * | grep /
```

There must be no output.  If there is output, you need to add another `sed` line
to your `fext` definition.

Now you can run `fext` against your entire collection of files to see how many
it thinks it recognizes, and how many it doesn't.

I am using a test group of 152 weakly-chosen files.  On three systems, I ran:

```
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
```

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS:

```
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
    137 ???
     15 jpg
```

FreeBSD 13.1:

```
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
  28 ???
  76 PDF
  15 jpg
  32 png
   1 tif,tiff
```

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

```
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
     28 ???
     15 jpg
     76 PDF
     32 png
      1 tif,tiff
```

Notice that we have found a bug in the `magic` file used by the `file` utility.  Fortunately, this is easy to fix in our `fext` function:

```
$ fext () {
  file -b --extension "$@" |
  sed -e 's-^jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif$-jpg-' |
  sed -e 's-^pdf$-PDF-' |
  sed -e 's-^tif,tiff$-tiff-' |
  cat
}
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
     28 ???
     15 jpg
     76 PDF
     32 png
      1 tiff
```

Excellent.  The important thing here is that there are NO slashes (or commas!).  We have
created a crude quantitative metric that permits us to see what percentage of
files are identified by `file`.  Specifically, `file` fails to identify 28 of the 152
files, or slightly over 18%.  We can further refine our `fext` function to assign a default
extension to files of those types that `file` can't identify.

```
$ fext () {
  file -b --extension "$@" |
  sed -e 's-^jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif$-jpg-' |
  sed -e 's-^pdf$-PDF-' |
  sed -e 's-^tif,tiff$-tiff-' |
  sed -e 's-^???$-unknown-' |
  cat
}
$ fext * | sort | uniq -c
     15 jpg
     76 PDF
     32 png
      1 tiff
     28 unknown
```

If we wish, we can `grep` that list and see the specific filenames of the files that `file`
can't identify:

```
$ for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && printf '%10s %s\n' "$(fext "$f")" "$f"; done | grep -w unknown
```

In my (weak) sample set, the "unknown" files are predominantly PostScript
files.  `file` does identify them as such, but the `magic` file has no
designated extension for PostScript files.

So, if we use `fext` to supply the extension for each file, the files that `file` can't
identify will receive the extension `unknown`.

```
$ for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv -vi "$f" "$f.$(fext "$f")"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Not easy. `file(1)` has an `--extension` option, but in my tests (Debian/bullseye) most of the files showed question marks (`???`).

And coding `case..esac` for every know file type most probably will not work out as `file` seems to detect at least 3000 file types:

```
❯ file -l | wc -l
3186
```

First I'd try to get the list of the file types in the given directory:

Note, [zsh-globbing](https://github.com/mika/zsh-pony#globbing--glob-qualifiers) used here:

```
❯ file -p -n -b .*(.) *(.) | sort | uniq
ASCII text
ASCII text, with no line terminators
ASCII text, with very long lines
ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
data
empty
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 300x300, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=0], baseline, precision 8, 96x96, components 3
JSON data
Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators, with escape sequences
Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
UTF-8 Unicode text
UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
very short file (no magic)
X11 Xauthority data
```

The following `find` line leads to the same output:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec file -p -n -b {} \; | sort | uniq
```

With this list, I'd create a kind of file-type-extension map / lookup file and use it to rename the files:

```
ext1;ASCII text
ext2;ASCII text, with no line terminators
ext3;ASCII text, with very long lines
ext4;ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
ext5;data
ext6;empty
ext7;JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 300x300, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=0], baseline, precision 8, 96x96, components 3
ext8;JSON data
ext9;Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators, with escape sequences
ext10;Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
ext11;UTF-8 Unicode text
ext12;UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
ext13;very short file (no magic)
ext14;X11 Xauthority data
```

HTH

Comment: may be with the --mime-encoding you can use that as extension

Answer (score 2):

With  `perl`-based `rename` and the `File::MimeInfo::Magic` perl  module (in `libfile-mimeinfo-perl` package on Debian-based systems, often installed by default in desktop installations as it's a dependency (recommend) of `xdg-utils`):

```
rename -n -- '
  use File::MimeInfo::Magic qw(mimetype extensions);
  my $ext; $_ .= ".$ext" if ! /\./ && ($ext = extensions mimetype$_)' *
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if that looks right).

Answer (score 1):

Guessing file type according to magic number can help solve this.

Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

This page lists most file types and their magic number, your script just read some bytes from offset and compare with signature, then add corresponding suffix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `file -b --extension` isn't very helpful because it returns `???` for many formats with known extensions.  Instead, start by cloning the directory of interest in case of any mishaps:

```bash
# using hard links
cp --link /path/to/originals /path/to/files

# using reflinks on supported file systems
cp --reflink=auto /path/to/originals /path/to/files
```

Then create a list of mime-types in the directory:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec file -b --mime-type {} \; | sort -u
```

Output looks like:

```
application/epub+zip
application/msword
application/pdf
application/zip
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/png
image/svg+xml
text/html
text/plain
text/rtf
text/xml
```

Now create a `bash` script `add_ext.sh` that renames files with the appropriate extension, according to mime-type, if needed.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ $# -lt 1 ] && echo "Usage: $0 <FILE>" && exit 1

mimetype=$(file -b --mime-type "$1")
extension="${1#**.}"
new_ext="unset"

case $mimetype in
   'application/epub+zip')
      new_ext="epub"
      ;;

   'application/msword')
      new_ext="doc"
      ;;

   'application/pdf')
      new_ext="pdf"
      ;;

   'application/zip')
      new_ext="zip"
      ;;

   'image/gif')
      new_ext="gif"
      ;;

   'image/jpeg')
      new_ext="jpeg"
      ;;

   'image/png')
      new_ext="png"
      ;;

   'image/svg+xml')
      new_ext="svg"
      ;;

   'text/html')
      new_ext="html"
      ;;

   'text/plain')
      new_ext="txt"
      ;;

   'text/rtf')
      new_ext="rtf"
      ;;

   'text/xml')
      new_ext="xml"
      ;;
esac

[ "$new_ext" != "unset" ] \
   && [ "$extension" != "$new_ext" ] \
   && [ ! -e "$1.$new_ext" ] \
   && mv "$1" "$1.$new_ext"
```

Don't forget `chmod +x add_ext.sh` before using `find` to run the script on the files:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec ./add_ext.sh {} \;
```